# select distinct on one column and return its row

Tags: mysql, sql

This question is most likely asked but I am having trouble searching for it.

I am looking to return a result set that comes from a unique column. This result set would include the unique column and another field.  The problem I am running into is that if I use distinct on both the unique column and its other field I will receive duplicates of the unique column because the 2nd field has two unique elements.

I will try to give a better demonstration of what I am looking to do.

**Workorder Table:**

```
JPNUM      DESCRIPTION
=====      ===========
FE-JPINSP  BLAH BLAH
FE-JPINSP  BLAH BLAH BLAH
FE-JPINSP  BLAH BLAH
LAB-JPINSP LAB INSP BLAH
```

**SQL:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT JPNUM FROM WORKORDER WHERE WORKTYPE = 'INSP' AND PARENT = ''
```

This query will work with just return unique JPNUM's.  But I also want to include the description associated with that JPNUM.  If I select on both the JPNUM and DESCRIPTION. I will receive duplicate JPNUM's Specifically FE-JPINSP.

I have left out a couple of the columns from the table. But you should get an idea.

Comment: Please learn to format your question properly. after 16 posts you should know there is a code block button.

Comment: How would you know which row to return the second value from if you have more than one rows matching the first value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't explain how to cope with an ambiguity in your data. There are in fact two values of your `DESCRIPTION` column associated with the value `F-JPINSP` in your `JPNUM` column.

I'll take a guess, that you want the lexically last (in this case longer) value.

Try this query.

```
SELECT JPNUM, 
       MAX(DESCRIPTION) AS DESCRIPTION
  FROM WORKORDER
 WHERE WORKTYPE = 'INSP'
   AND PARENT = ''
 GROUP BY JPNUM
 ORDER BY JPNUM
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply group by JPNUM and take what DESCRIPTION you like best with MIN, MAX or GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT JPNUM, MIN(DESCRIPTION)
FROM WORKORDER 
WHERE WORKTYPE = 'INSP' AND PARENT = ''
GROUP BY JPNUM;
```